# Restrict users to create data only for themselves

Tags: spring, spring-boot, authorization, bean-validation

I have a microservices architecture deployed on kubernetes with istio gateway, AWS cognito used for Authentication. Now when the user logs in to the APP, he can create/view data using the API's. The mobile FE application sends the "userId" of the logged in user for which data needs to be created or fetched. JWT token from cognito is sent with each request which has the userId in claims.

What I want to achieve is restrict my API's such that the data should be created only for the used whose token is sent or the data should be fetched only for the user in the JWT token. For example consider the below request

```
POST /api/data/submit

{
    "name": "John doe",
    "address": "131 parklane street",
    "userId": 1000,
    ...
}
```

In the above request, any user(**Say id:90**) can create the data for user id **1000**.

The solution currently implemented in the project is using Spring Aspects. The drawback is that it works **only for API's where userId is sent as PathVariable** though it can be modified to check request objects using reflection but that wouldn't be efficient.

The solution I have in mind is using Bean Validation. I create a custom annotation which can be applied at field and parameter level with a custom validator and validate that the value should match the userId present in the token.

I tried searching for best approach but mostly found solutions for ROLE based authorization though what I want to achieve is different.

Any guidance would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In one of my project we are doing the same. In such calls, we are not sending userId field. Services are extracting the same from token instead of depending upon POST data field.

Comment: Thanks. I suggested this as well. But my TL said it doesn't feel like a REST API approach :) though this is the correct approach.

Comment: REST or not depends on API and the resource. For e.g., you are managing Profile for a user. So /profile with POST call without userId make sense. If in your case, it doesn't make sense then custom validator is the simple approach (not best/good) :)